# Anchoring the Action URL of a Form

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a function that leads users to a file called "comments2.php":

```
<form  action="http://www...com/.../comments/comments2.php" method="post">
```

On comments2.php, data passed over from the form is inserted into MySQL:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO comment VALUES (NULL, %d, %d, '%s', NULL)", $uid, $subid, $comment);

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Then, later in comments2.php, I am using a query that loops through entries meeting certain criteria.  The loop contains a row with the following information:

```
echo '<td rowspan="3" class="commentname1" id="comment-' . $row["commentid"] . '">'.stripslashes($row["comment"]).'</td>';
```

For the function above, I would like the URL to be anchored by the highest value of "commentid" for `id="comment-' . $row["commentid"] . '"`

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: what does it mean "anchored"? In terms of code please

Comment: I would like the top of the browser to be flush with the comment that has the highest value of commentid.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
$id=mysql_insert_id();
header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."#anchor$id");
exit;
```

Comment: THis looks promising... but I'm confused about what to use for $id and  #anchor.  Do I need to change them?

Comment: Should be `header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}#comment-$id");`